# Cannot find jni function in Sequoyah

Tags: android, gdb, android-ndk

I've set up Sequoyah according to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/ndk_guide.
I'm testing it on the hello-jni sample that came with the NDK. It works fine without the debugging stuff, and also up to the step where the guide tells you to run ndk-gdb. However, when I attempt to run the C debug part in Eclipse, it says

```
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/system/bin/linker: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libc.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstdc++.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libm.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
liblog.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libz.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libbinder.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libexpat.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcrypto.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libgabi++.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libicuuc.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libicui18n.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libssl.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstlport.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnativehelper.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnetutils.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libGLESv2_dbg.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libEGL.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libwpa_client.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhardware_legacy.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libpixelflinger.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhardware.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libemoji.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libjpeg.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libskia.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libui.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libGLESv2.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libgui.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libcamera_client.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsqlite.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libdvm.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libGLESv1_CM.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libETC1.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libsonivox.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_foundation.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libmedia.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libnfc_ndef.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libusbhost.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libharfbuzz.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libbluedroid.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libdbus.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libandroid_runtime.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libvorbisidec.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_yuv.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libdrmframework.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libchromium_net.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_amrnb_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_enc_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright_avc_common.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libstagefright.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libmtp.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libexif.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libmedia_jni.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libbcc.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libbcinfo.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libRS.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
librs_jni.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libandroid.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libwebcore.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhello-jni.so: No such file or directory.
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Function "Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI" not defined.
```

So the last few lines seem to be the problem, but it's very weird, since it works fine when you run it as normal, but the debugger can't find it for some reason.

```
Error while mapping shared library sections:
libhello-jni.so: No such file or directory.
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Function "Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI" not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I deleted the line from gdb2.setup as the tutorial says, it changed the line ending. I noticed it when I opened the file with Visual Studio on accident and it asked me if I wanted to normalize the line endings. So I just did as it said, with the Unix LF option